# Transfer call to custom extension to pause recording and dial externally

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

We have a call centre and record calls using the MixMonitor.

We need to be able to transfer some calls externally, but when we do so the call recording continues. This is fine, apart from calls to a specific number. What I've done to try to resolve this is create a custom extension. When we want to transfer the call externally to this particular number, we can transfer to this extension instead which can stop the recording and transfer on.

If I call the extension (`2123`) from my own personal extension it seems to work as expected and calls the external number. If I am on the phone currently (both external and internal calls) and I try to transfer the call to this extension, I get a voice message saying "The number you have dialled is not in service. Please check the number and try again.").

My config (in `/etc/asterisk/extensions_custom.conf`) is:

`[from-internal]
; For the purpose of SO, I've removed other custom extensions here
exten => 2123,1,Answer
exten => 2123,1,StopMixmonitor()
exten => 2123,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=[number-removed])
exten => 2123,n,Dial(SIP/[sipname-removed]/[externalnumber-removed],120,r)
exten => 2123,n,Hangup()`

I'm using the FreePBX distro, FreePBX version 12.0.76.3, Asterisk version 11.18.0.

Can anyone help me fix the issue so a transfer to this extension works too? Thanks for your help.

I'm also open to alternative solutions to the same problem, but I can't help thinking that I'm 99% of the way there with this solution already.

*EDIT: I'm suspicious that the problem is to do with the `[from-internal]`, but am not sure what it should be instead.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is more elegant solution for your problem using FreePBX gui.

1) You need to create new outbound route in gui. Put your destination number in much pattern (for example 987654). You can add callerid details too in Route CID field.

2) Make sure that Call Recording is set to "Never"

3) Make sure that you set proper trunk

4) Put this route on top of all other on the right side.

This solution will turn off call recordings for all calls to 987654 number. If you need call recordings remain to direct calls to 987654, but don't need recordings only when you transfer call, then you need to add prefix in point 1 like 123 and then calls to 123-987654 will not be recorded(will use our new created route) and calls to 987654 will be follow regular logic, what you have in dial-plans.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working :) I'll give it a better test when I'm back in the office tomorrow. It is certainly a much cleaner solution than I was creating!